# Append Sum Formula

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have one cell with the formula:

```
=SUM(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1....)
```

And I wanted to append the value of F1 so:

```
=SUM(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+F1....)
```

*not* `=SUM(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1....) + F1` since I want F1 in the brackets

How can I do this?

Note, the values don't follow a pattern so even if I put 1 it can be:

```
 =SUM(A6+BC2+C1023+D1+E1+F1....)
```

Comment: What would trigger the addition?

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you elaborate

Comment: How is there a difference between `SUM(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+F1....) ` and `SUM(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1....) + F1`??

Comment: I guess there isn't but I want F1 inside the brackets. Let me edit

Comment: Is there a trigger or do you just want to append every formula with a new cell?  It is hard to visualize what you want.  Is there a series of formula or is it just one?  If it is one then manually adding would be quickest if it is many then a quick find/replace will work.  So it is hard to help you with vba when we do not fully understand the why.

Comment: I have one formula and I want to append its argument with another value. Simple as that. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: lol you're going to have to work on articulating yourself. Not sure if it gets clearer than what Scott said XD

Comment: Think of this. In my spreadsheet I have many columns with every date. So a column for today, column for yesterday ect.. with a number. I have a grand total for those numbers. Every time a date is added or new column I need to append the Grand total column with that date column number. So my VBA script adds the current date number to the sum of the grand total

Comment: What determines what cell you have in your formula? You can use `SumIfs()` to have a more dynamic formula than manually adding cells.  Also, do you need this in VBA, or a formula? It's not too clear. Also, please post your code if it's relevant to your `Sum` question.

Comment: IF your formula was in F14 then `Range("F14").Formula = Replace(Range("F14").Formula, ")", "+" & Selection.Address(0, 0) & ")")`

Comment: Why don't you just add the rows? `SUM(1:4)` for instance. So if you add a column it gets automatically added to the grand total.

Comment: If by "append" you mean concatenate two strings then use "&" so:
="Hello " & "World"

Outputs "Hello World". Was this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before:

[image]

The macro:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    With Range("A2")
        .Formula = Mid(.Formula, 1, Len(.Formula) - 1) & "+F1)"
    End With
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]

This is one way to edit a formula with VBA.